# Exactly how to use nonnull in certain cases in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nullable, non-nullable, objective-c-nullability

I have read many posts about nullability but I can't for the life of me make my warnings go away.  Here are a couple of examples:

```
playPause = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"Pause"]];
[imagePropertiesFileHandle writeData:[header dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Each of these gets this warning: "implicit conversion from nullable pointer 'NSData * _Nullable' to non-nullable pointer type 'NDSata* _Nonnull'

Surrounding the code with NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/End doesn't work either.

I've tried a wide variety of combinations of (nonnull) __nonnull, etc and can't seem to find the magic location of keywords to make the warning go away.

Comment: What is `header`?  From the looks of it, `dataUsingEncoding:` returns a nullable NSData object, while `imagePropertiesFileHandle` expects a `nonnull` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `NSString dataUsingEncoding:` method can return `nil`. But the `NSFileHandle writeData:` doesn't accept a `nil` parameter.

Split this line:

```
[imagePropertiesFileHandle writeData:[header dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Into these:

```
NSData *data = [header dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (data) {
    [imagePropertiesFileHandle writeData:data];
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I get it now and I see how that applies to my other example.